# How can I create a child theme in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I would like to use my existing theme but with some small changes. Is there any way in Prestashop to create a child theme?

Comment: You can read the complete guide how to achieve this on: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/reference/template-inheritance/parent-child-feature/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have an installed theme on your store(`root/themes` folder) that will be used as a parent for your child theme.
Create a new folder in `/themes` folder( For example: childtheme)
copy below files from parent theme folder to child theme folder

```
 ├── config
 │   └── theme.yml
 └── preview.png
```

open `theme.yml` file of child theme and specify which theme should be used as a parent.

```
parent: classic
name: childtheme
display_name: My first child Theme
version: 1.0.0
assets:
  use_parent_assets: true
```

Now go to back office where you can see a new child theme will appear and you are all set.